# How to find the some word in the text file

Tags: python, regex

I have a file text, I want filter some word in the text with condition:

1) same the length and starting with same a letter

2) find words with the at least 2 correctly placed letters

For example:

word = bubal

text

```
byres
brits
blurb
bulks
bible
debug
debut
```

and want to output: `['bulks', 'bible']` with  `bulks` have 'b' and 'u' correctly placed and `bible` have 2 `b` correctly placed with `bubal` 
My ideal to find the word with starting a lettre and so find the word same length and then find the word correct 2nd condition
But I write the code find the word starting by using `re` and it don't run good

```py
import re
with open('words.txt','r') as file:
    liste = file.read()
    word = re.findall('[b]\w+',liste)
    print(word)
```

My code return the `['byres','brits','bulks','but','bug']`
How to fix it and find word flows condition

Comment: `filter the word same at last 2 position letter` <-- what does this actually mean?

Comment: exemple: I had 2 word `bubal` and `brits` same 1 lettre at position `b` but `bubal` and `bulks` same 2 lettre at position

Comment: Your requirements are unclear, which means that you are not ready to ask a question here yet.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: so you are telling like you want the output `['but',bulks','bug']` from this array `['byres','brits','bulks','but','bug']`?

Comment: sorry, my english is not good, so question wasn't clear

Comment: Are you telling like,  you want to filter the words which contains beginning 2 letter are same.?

Comment: Please add the some more sample input. Because what you have added and the result both are not same.

Comment: @mkHun No, I want filter the words with contains beginning 1 letter same and the other letter can be in any position

Comment: @mkHun I add some exemple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edited based on your comment.*

This may be what you're after:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

def find_best_letter_matches(lines, target):
    m = []
    m_count = 0

    for line in lines:
        count = sum(map(lambda x: x[0] == x[1], zip(line, target)))
        if count > m_count:
            m = []
            m_count = count
        if count == m_count:
            m.append(line)

    return m

def find_n_letter_matches(lines, target, n):
    m = []

    for line in lines:
        count = sum(map(lambda x: x[0] == x[1], zip(line, target)))
        if count >= n:
            m.append(line)

    return m

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
        lines = f.read().split('\n')
        best_matches = find_best_letter_matches(lines, 'bubal')
        n_matches = find_n_letter_matches(lines, 'bubal', 2)
        print('Best letter matches', best_matches)
        print('At least 2 letters match', n_matches)
```

The functions compare each line to the target, letter by letter, and counts the number of matches. The first then returns the list of the highest matching lines, and the second returns all that match with `n` or more letters.

The output with your example text (with bubal added) is:

```
Best letter matches ['bubal']
At least 2 letters match ['bulks', 'bible', 'bubal']
```

Comment: If `bubal` in a file text, the function return the `bubal`, I need the all word which had at last 2 correctly placed letters

Comment: @vodanh You just need to put in a little tweak i.e. don't reset the _m_ list and set the _m\_count_ variable to 1

Comment: As @kerwei mentioned, it is a small tweak to the function. I've shown both in the code so you can see the difference.

Comment: @laenkeio and @kerwei, can you explain for me why `map(lambda x: x[0] == x[1], zip(line, target))` can compare each letter in the word? I see 'x[0] == x[1]' like 'line == target'

Comment: @vodanh It's easier to explain through a little experiment. Power up your python console and run the following: `for i in zip('bubal', 'bulks'): print(i)` and compare it to `for i in zip(['bubal'], ['bulks']): print(i)`. Python strings are iterable and with the `zip()` function, it gets unpackaged nicely for you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
wordToSearch = "bubal"
singlesChar = list(wordToSearch)

finalArray = []
with open('words.txt','r') as file:
    liste = file.readlines()
    for each in liste:
        each = each.rstrip()
        fn = list(each)
        flag = 0
        for i in range(0,len(singlesChar)):
            if(fn[i] == singlesChar[i]):
                flag+=1
        if(flag >= 2): finalArray.append(each)



print(finalArray)
```